# Is it possible to represent a context-free grammar with first-order logic?

Tags: prolog, ebnf, first-order-logic

Briefly, I have a EBNF grammar and so a parse-tree, but I do not know if there is a procedure to translate it in First Order Logic.

For example:

```
DR ::= E and P
P ::= B | (and P)* | (or P)*
B ::= L | P (and L P)
L ::= a
```

Comment: Mind that Prolog is not exactly with *first-order logic*. Secondly, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202543/how-is-this-context-free-grammar-using-difference-lists-in-prolog-functioning) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  The general pattern for translating a production of the form

A ::= B C ... D

is to paraphrase is declaratively as saying

> A sequence of terminals *s* is an *A* (or:  *A* generates the sequence *s*, if you prefer that formulation) if:
>
> - *s* is the concatenation of *s_1*, *s_2*, ... *s_n*, and
> - *s_1* is a *B* / *B* generates the sequence *s_1*, and
> - *s_2* is a *C* / *C* generates the sequence *s_2*, and
> - ...
> - *s_n* is a *D* / *D* generates the sequence *s_n*.

Assuming we write these in the obvious way using a *generates* predicate, and that we can write concatenation using a || operator, your first rule becomes (if I am right to guess that E and P are non-terminals and "and" is a terminal symbol) something like

```
generates(DR,s) ⊃ generates(E,s1) 
                  ∧ generates(and,s2)
                  ∧ generates(P,s3)
                  ∧ s = s1 || s2 || s3
```

To establish the consequent (i.e. prove that *s* is an *A*), prove the antecedents.  As long as the grammar does actually generate some sentences, and as long as you have some premises defining the "generates" relation for terminal symbols, the proof will be straightforward.

Prolog definite-clause grammars are a beautiful instantiation of this pattern.  It takes some of us a while to understand and appreciate the use of difference lists in DCGs, but they handle the partitioning of *s* into subsequences and the association of the subsequences with the different parts of the right hand side much more elegantly than the simple translation into logic given above.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.
Anyway my problem is related to FOL only. What about the || operator? It is not in FOL right?
In the rules you mentioned are not listed NT like B and L, this means I have to add s4 and s5?

Comment: Whether the flavor of first-order logic you are using has a concatenation operator is a question the documentation should answer. Few definitions of first-order logic in logic textbooks are likely to define one, but some forms of logic intended for reasoning about software or parsing do.  The rules given in the answer are a translation of one production in your grammar (the first); the other productions will need similar rules.  None of your productions has exactly five substrings on the right-hand side, so variables named s4 and s5 would be surprising.